# Difference between compiling and setup.sh

Tags: software-installation, compiling

What is the essential difference between apply this lines:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

and this command:

```
./setup.sh
```

Because depending the code, must be done one or the other. Essentially, is it the same?

Answer (score 2):

Compiling does exactly that, compiles source code into a binary executable format.  setup.sh is just a filename for a shell script, an executable text file, that could do any number of things.  It could contain instructions that automate compiling source code, or it could just copy a bunch of files around, make directories, etc.

Usually it's a good idea to read the Readme as well as any setup scripts and such inside packages you download to see how the developer(s) intended for the software to be installed and used.